# object oriented make class

Tags: python-3.x, oop

i want make class that take lists and give the mean of lists

the object is like this  A(3 #number of people,list_of_age[15, 16, 17],list_of_height[172,165,166],list_of _weight[64,67,65])

```
import statistics

class student:
             
    def __init__(self, len, list_of_age ,list_of_height, list_of_weight):      
        self.l = len
        self.age = list_of_age
        self.height = list_of_height
        self.weight = list_of_weight

    def age(self):
        statistics.mean(self.age)

    def height(self):
        statistics.mean(self.height)

    def weight(self):
        statistics.mean(self.weight)

# part of input

lines = []
while True:
    line = input().split()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break

z1=[]

A=student(lines[0],list(map(lambda x:int(x), lines[1])),list(map(lambda x:int(x), lines[2])),list(map(lambda x:int(x), lines[3])))

z1.append(A.age())
```

but it take this error

```
z1.append(A.age())
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

any clue

Comment: why do you not use the `return` statement? just calling your function does exsctly nothing - it computes something and forgets about it. See dupe for what @Hampus mentioned

Comment: In the class-definition, you are creating the method `age`, `height` and `weight`, however, inside of the `__init__` method, you're shadowing those methods by assigning the lists over the same namespace. If you change the methods to something like `mean_age` instead of `age`, then your code should work.

Comment: thanks guys it is work